# Push notification does not work for signed app

Tags: ios, push-notification

There are some problem with push notifications. If I run app on device push notifications come well, but if I archive app and download it from 'diawi' push notifications stops come. And on any test device it does not work too.

Does anybody have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Exporting IPA you must check IPA is creating with valid profile or not. please check attached image for reference .[image]

Comment: Yeah! It helps. xCode set up wrong provision profile

Answer (score 2):

[image]whenever you make Archive and try to upload ipa it will change aps environment development to production. it will install with distribution profile. you can change in schema according to your requirement or you can only check (production)sandbox false at server.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the scheme for Archive. If it is different then you will have to make it identical to the run setting.